# Format zsh prompt according to the value of an environment variable

Tags: zsh, tmux, prompt, interactive

I want the color of my zsh prompt to be decided based on whether I'm inside a tmux session or not. In bash, it can be done by checking the value of $TMUX, but I can't find an equivalent method in zsh. Is it possible in zsh?

Comment: The `TMUX` variable is independent of the shell you use. What is the issue you're having?

Comment: In bash I could put `${TMUX:+colorcode}` in the PS1 variable, to set the color, it doesn't work in zsh and I can't find a similar way to do it in the manual.

Comment: The `%{x.t.f%}` can only test for a predefined set of conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In zsh, the [`prompt_subst` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPTSUBST) is off by default. If you want to use variable substitutions in your prompt, turn it on.

```
setopt prompt_subst
PS1='$foo'
```

For `$TMUX`, though, you don't need this. The value doesn't change during the session, so you can initialize `PS1` when the shell starts.

```
setopt prompt_subst
if (($+TMUX)); then
  PS1='[tmux:${TMUX_PANE//\%/%%}] %# '
else
  PS1='[not tmux] %# '
fi
```

Note that [prompt expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion) happens after variable susbtitution, this is why the percent signs in the variable's value need to be protected.

Answer (score 2):

When launched tmux will inherit the environment variables of the shell that launched it (like all other processes).
From that point tmux will then bestow those same environment variables onto the pseudo terminals it creates. 
Except for one important environment variable

```
$TERM
```

The tmux server will hold the value give to it by the original shell.
You can query this with

```
<C-b>:display-message "$TERM"
```

on my system this gives `xterm-256color`.
but all pseudo terminals tmux starts will get something like

```
$TERM=screen
```

on my system I set the pseudo terminals to `TERM=screen-256color` so that programs (vim) running inside tmux know the color capabilities of the terminal. You can do this with this tmux command

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Either way you can check for the presence of this string and set your prompt accordingly

`~/.zshrc`

```
if [[ $TERM == *screen* ]]; then
    # you're in tmux, congratulate yourself :)
    # set your tmux prompt here
else
    # you're not in tmux
    # set your fallback prompt here
fi
```